# Exception not caught on PHP5.6 server

Tags: php, exception, error-handling

I am a bit stuck with an web-app I currently develop. I decided to **use Exceptions together with try/catch-blocks** more deliberately.

Nonetheless; I developed **locally using PHP7**, and when I just uploaded the app to a **PHP5 server**, all those exceptions are not catched any longer. Instead, script execution stops with a fatal error. I have read something about major changes concerning Exceptions with PHP7, but all information I found is very vague.

Script-stop is not so much a problem, but catching and "modifying" the error is VERY important in this case, since the script is run by AJAX call and must return an JSON-formatted error-message.

**Main File:**

```
try {

    if (!$this->validateNonce($this->postParams['upload-nonce']))
    throw new Exception('Upload failed because nonce could not be verified.');

    new FloImage(
        $this->postParams['basename'],
        true,
        $this->fileParams['uploadfile']
    );

} catch (Throwable $e) {

    echo json_encode(array('error' => $e->getMessage()));
    die();

}
```

`FloImage()` checks some information (name, file-size, etc.) and in case of an error throws an exception this way:

```
throw new Exception(_('My error message.'));
```

Help about how to make the try-catch-block work with PHP5 would be appreciated! Thank you in advance...

Comment: what is the fatal error you are getting?

Comment: I always get the error I am throwing. Fatal Error: My Message.

Comment: `Throwable` is the base interface in PHP7 -> [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/class.throwable.php) I think you can't catch it because `Exception` does'nt implement the interface in PHP5

Comment: Thanks! What do I have to use to have it work with both PHP5 ad PHP7? "Exception $e"?

Comment: `Exception $e` should work, since most exceptions are derived from `Exception`. And as you throw an `Exception` it will work anyway in PHP7 and PHP5.

Comment: Sounds logical. I will test it, but I assume it works. I just didn't notice `Throwable` wasn't there in PHP5. If you write a short answer with this info, I could mark it as correct? (Edit: It worked perfectly...)

Comment: @JonathanWeber In addition I submited a short answer with working examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Throwable` is an interface introduced in PHP7. From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/class.throwable.php) it states:

> Throwable is the base interface for any object that can be thrown via a throw statement in PHP 7, including Error and Exception.

Therefore if you want to use your code with PHP5 you have to catch the `Exception` itself. I.e.

```
try {
    throw new Exception('Some exception');
}
catch (\Exception $e) // use the backslash to comply with namespaces
{
    echo($e->getMessage());
    die();
}
```

This will work as long as the thrown exception is derived from `Exception`. i.e.

```
class SpecialException extends Exception {}

try {
    throw new SpecialException('Some exception');
}
catch (\Exception $e) // use the backslash to comply with namespaces
{
    echo($e->getMessage());
    die();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

May be you're looking for [set_error_handler()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) which is used to write user-defined error handler function. So set your error handler at the top of the execution of the script.

Don't forget to put [restore_error_handler()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.restore-error-handler.php) at the end of the script to restore the previous error handler function.

You can recover your script accordingly in **set_error_handler()** function.

Comment: I would like to use try/catch, not error-handlers. Thanks anyway for your suggestion!